# Acquire valid web url from Host.TopLevelDomain C#

Tags: c#, http, url, web, uri

Given a string which contains a partial url, for example "google.com"

Is it possible to get a valid URI from that string?

The expected result would be the same as you get from placing google.com in any web browsers address bar.
Ex. http://www.google.com/

In the end I want ot pass this value to a new Uri object so I can use it in a HttpWebRequest to retrieve Favicons.

Comment: asp.net or what else?

Comment: This is actually in a WPF application, so I can't rely on a client to do the work for me.
The entire problem is to allow a user to enter some text, be it a search or a web site, and have it work as well as any other web browser address entry/search.
I'm effectively trying to replicate some features of the Chrome Omnibox.

Comment: I've worked around the issue by just letting the Uri construction fail gracefully, but I don't think it is a solid approach to solving this problem.

Comment: I've tried some approaches too... not so much success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var URL = "google.com/Somepath/";
            var CorrectedURL = new TopLevelURL(URL,"http").ParsedURL;
            Console.WriteLine(CorrectedURL);
            Console.Read();
        }


    }

    public class TopLevelURL
    {

        private string URL = "";
        private string Protocol = "";
        public string ParsedURL { get; private set; }

        public TopLevelURL(string _URL,string WantedProtocol)
        {
            URL = _URL;
            Protocol = (WantedProtocol == "http" ? "http://" : "https://") ?? "http://";
            ParseURL();
        }

        private void ParseURL()
        {
            if (URL.ToLower().Contains("http"))
            {
                //If the URL is provided with the protocol check the validity of URL
                if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(URL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
                    throw new Exception("Malformed URL!");

                //If the URL is provided with the protocol and is valid, just get the absolute URL. e.g: http://helloworld.com
                URL = new Uri(URL).AbsoluteUri.Replace(new Uri(URL).AbsolutePath, "");
            }
            else
            { 
                //If the URL does not have the protocol then start constructing it with the protocol
                URL = Protocol + URL;
                if(!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(URL,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
                    throw new Exception("Could not parse the URL. Invalid character before the domain name!");

                URL = new Uri(URL).AbsoluteUri.Replace(new Uri(URL).AbsolutePath,"");

            }
            ParsedURL = URL;
        }



    }
```

This is simplified. You can check http://doepud.co.uk/blog/anatomy-of-a-url to come up with more strict rules. The above example checks the simple protocol and spits out the URL after removing the path.

Comment: This is a good answer, though I was hoping for an 'automagic' way of doing it.  I've found no such automagic way so far though, this will probably be my accepted answer if no one comes up with anything better.